# How can I authenticate with atlassian bitbucket API?

Tags: python, authentication, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I am trying to see some example of how to connect to atlassian bitbucket (used to be STASH) API and I don't see any examples of how does one authenticate to start retrieving data like, projects, repos etc.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use OAuth for authentication instead of user passwords and basic auth. For this you need to have an application link in place. I blogged about how to communicate with Atlassian applications by using OAuth in Python [here](https://www.mibexsoftware.com/2015/11/13/how-to-use-oauth-with-atlassian-products/). This will also work in Bitbucket Server.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Michael